# Error al intentar subir un archivo a servidor diferente

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

Tengo una aplicación la cual los usuarios pueden subir archivos y estos se almacenan en el mismo servidor donde esta mi aplicación subida es decir los archivos quedan guardados en la misma aplicación, pero he visto comentarios donde no recomiendan hacer eso, si no tener un servidor diferente para almacenar los archivos, así que tengo un servidor diferente con la dirección ip 192.168.0.36 en la misma red, pero estoy teniendo un problema y es que al intentar subir archivos a ese servidor me genera un error que pareciera que no reconoce mi servidor pues el error es el siguiente InnerException = {"No se pudo encontrar el archivo 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\descarga.png'.":"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\descarga.png"}. 
Este es mi codigo C#:

```
protected void actualizar_foto(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (file_foto.HasFile)
        {
            string Id_Usuario = Request.QueryString["Id_Usuario"].ToString();
            string serverName = @"\\192.168.0.36\E$\INTRANET\PRUE\";
            string folder = "PRUE/";
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file_foto.FileName)
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("reyhj", "fvgbfmhj");
            client.UploadFile(serverName, "POST", file_foto.FileName)
            // Upload to Hosted Server.
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            Uri uri = new Uri(serverName + folder + fileName);
            webClient.UploadFile(uri, "POST", fileName)
            DCL.Int_Usuarios obj = new DCL.Int_Usuarios();
            obj.Anexo_Foto = uri.ToString();
            obj.Id_Usuario = Convert.ToInt32(Id_Usuario);
            Int_Usuarios_BRL.InsertOrUpdate(obj, 45);
        }
        Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString(), true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Write(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Pues, en el IIS Revisa Virtual Folders -> Este lo apuntas hacia otro lado (otro server)

Comment: he intentado ya muchas cosas también esa pero sigue generando el mismo error

Comment: ¿La ruta está bien? En el IIS debería estar en el wwwroot de la página

Comment: no lo esta pues la distribución de los archivos es entra a la ip luego a la partición e luego las carpetas intranet luego prue, y ahi es donde se almacenara los archivos, wwwrooot es obligatorio?

Comment: ¿Sabes configurar el IIS para servir sitios web?

Comment: revisa este par de enlaces: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/application/ y https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-iis.html

Comment: pero me refiero al servidor por guardas los archivos, ese no lo tengo por medio de iis, solo el proyecto donde esta mi aplicacion